# Confused about json Date(####-##) to .NET DateTime Conversion

Tags: c#, json, date, datetime, utc

I'm a little confused about the conversion of the Newtonsoft JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode is making to a date that comes in the /Date(####)/ format. When it comes with the UTC format it subtracts the offset to the date and in my case that makes that change my date. For example I sent this date:

Local date: 9/3/2014 10:20:00 AM

UTC date: 9/3/2014 10:20:00 AM - 05:00

Unix date: 1409739600000-0500

but when I do this:

```
var xml = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode("{ \"data\": \"/Date(1409739600000-0500)/\" }");
Console.WriteLine("f unix-xml:\t\t\t" + xml.OuterXml);
```

The output is:

```
<data>2014-09-03T05:20:00-05:00</data>
```

What I'm doing wrong? or I'm misunderstanding something?

Comment: You don’t seem to get what an “UTC date” would be. The offset `-05:00` belongs to the *local* date. It’s the offset *from* UTC. So a local time `10:20` would be `15:20` UTC. Please show how you are creating the date, and how you are serializing it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Poke was right, the Unix date I was using was not the correspond date for my local date. Since the unix date is in UTC the miliseconds should be in UTC kind time and no based in my local time.